# Django reversed OneToOne relation with select_related

Tags: django, django-models

I have below model and I want to perform below query:

```
Post.objects.select_related(
    'previous_post', 'next_post'
).get(id=some_id)


# models.py
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    content = models.TextField()
    previous_post = models.OneToOneField('self', null=True, blank=True,
                                         related_name='next_post',
                                         on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

For some reason it does not work with `next_post` parameter, as I get following error:

`raise IndexError("Number of args exceeds number of fields")
IndexError: Number of args exceeds number of fields`

Theoretically I can live without `select_related`, but I would prefer not to give up it in this case and I am really curious whether I am doing something wrong or this is just a Django bug.

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/konrad/PycharmProjects/jdg/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 381, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/home/konrad/PycharmProjects/jdg/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 240, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/konrad/PycharmProjects/jdg/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1074, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/home/konrad/PycharmProjects/jdg/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 72, in __iter__
    rel_populator.populate(row, obj)
  File "/home/konrad/PycharmProjects/jdg/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1715, in populate
    obj = self.model_cls.from_db(self.db, self.init_list, obj_data)
  File "/home/konrad/PycharmProjects/jdg/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 460, in from_db
    new = cls(*values)
  File "/home/konrad/PycharmProjects/jdg/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 372, in __init__
    raise IndexError("Number of args exceeds number of fields")
IndexError: Number of args exceeds number of fields
```

Comment: Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: `env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py in __init__, line 372`

Comment: Above was last line, in the post you have access to full traceback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bug in Django. I can reproduce in 1.8 and 1.9, but not in the master branch.

Doing a git bisect, tt appears to have been fixed by [ticket 26207](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26207), so it should be fixed in Django 1.10.